# How would I quicksort with multiple criteria in Python?

Tags: python, quicksort

Right now, my code looks like this:

```
def partition(lista, inicio, fim):
i = (inicio - 1)
pivot = lista[fim][uf]

for j in range(inicio, fim):
    if lista[j][uf] <= pivot:

        i += 1
        lista[i], lista[j] = lista[j], lista[i]

lista[i + 1], lista[fim] = lista[fim], lista[i + 1]
return (i + 1)


def quickSort(lista,inicio,fim):
    pilha = []
    pilha.append((inicio,fim))

    while pilha:      
        pos = pilha.pop()
        fim, inicio = pos[1], pos[0]
        piv = partition(lista,inicio,fim)

        if piv-1 > inicio:
            pilha.append((inicio,piv-1))

        if piv+1 < fim:
            pilha.append((piv+1,fim))
```

But it's only sorting by UF, which is one of the many keys in my array. How would I include another key so it can sort with UF is the same?

Comment: Why are you defining your own `quickSort` function instead of using the built-in `sort`?

Comment: This is for college, the teacher made us do it like this. It's also why I'm not using pandas or something like that. I actually have to do it the hard way.

Answer (score 0):

The classic way to sort by an arbitrary transform of your items (such as the values that correspond to specific keys in a dictionary, or attributes of an item), is the Decorate-Sort-Undecorate pattern.

The way it works is first you "decorate" the items in your list by replacing them with a tuple that starts with each of the values you want to sort by (most significant first), and ends with the original value.

Then you sort the list as usual, comparing the items directly (just like if you were sorting a list of numbers).

Finally, once the list of transformed values is sorted, you can reverse the transform you applied to the items, discarding tuple and values you don't need any more and just leaving the original items.

Here's how you could add this to your `quickSort` function. Here, I'm assuming `uf` is a sequence containing all the keys you care about:

```
def quickSort(lista,inicio,fim):
    for i, value in enumerate(lista):                        # decorate step
        lista[i] = tuple(value[x] for x in uf) + (i, lista)  # index i used as final tiebreaker

    pilha = []
    pilha.append((inicio,fim))

    while pilha:      
        pos = pilha.pop()
        fim, inicio = pos[1], pos[0]
        piv = partition(lista,inicio,fim)

        if piv-1 > inicio:
            pilha.append((inicio,piv-1))

        if piv+1 < fim:
            pilha.append((piv+1,fim))

    for i, value in enumerate(lista):                        # undecorate step
        lista[i] = value[-1]
```

You'll want to change the `partition` function to compare items directly, rather than indexing by `uf`.

A slightly more sophisticated approach removes the globally looked up `uf` sequence of keys and instead uses a `key` function. The function can do whatever it wants, as long as it returns a comparable value. The decorate step would become `lista[i] = (key(value), i, value)`. This is how Python's builtin sorting code works (though it doesn't use quicksort).

Comment: Your response actually made me more confused, so I'll try to explain better my problem, bear with me as english is not my main language, so I have trouble explaining some things. Lista is a matrix, and I want to use `lista[n][0]` as a key to sort the matrix, if `lista[n][0]` is equal to `lista[n+1][0]`, then I'll use `lista[n][1]` as the key. Is that what you understood? Also, I'm having trouble doing what you said. Sorry for being a noob!

Comment: the `key` argument takes a callable value for `sort` and `sorted` in python. Sort/Sorted with key implements the `decorate-sort-dedecorate` pattern without needing to implement any of this.